# converting from timestamp to date is diffrent from localhost and from server

Tags: typescript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

im developing app with firebase as the server and flutter as the front.
the scenario is that i upload new document with timestamp which contain the current time like that:

```
"timestamp": DateTime.now().toString(),
```

while i run it as a localhost i see that the document saved the current time as well but while i run it on the cloude server its save it +3 hours. i know that its related to the UTC which in my country the UTC is +3. the line on the server is:

```
console.log(req.body.timestamp);
let timeStamp = new Date(req.body.timestamp);
console.log(timeStamp);
```

for example the prints on localhost to that string `2020-05-23 23:16:03.735472` was:

```
>  2020-05-23 23:16:03.735472
>  2020-05-23T20:16:03.735Z
```

but from the server it was:

```
>  2020-05-23 23:16:03.735472
>  2020-05-23T23:16:03.735Z
```

why does its happen?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple timezone issue.  Date data types don't store timezone data in them.  However, when they're printed, they typically use the default configured timezone for the local system that's doing the formatting.  Unless you want the local timezone of the machine, you shouldn't trust that string format at all.

One thing to point out is that storing date/time objects as formatted string is typically not a very good idea.  Firestore has a proper timestamp data type that always stores timestamp values using UTC timezone offset (+0), which is the norm for all date/time types for all modern computer systems.  You should use this to store your dates, then format them on the client in the specific timezone of your choice.  There are a lot of date utilities out there that will do these conversions for you.

If you want to store the current time in a document, it's typical to specify [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/serverTimestamp.html) as the value, and Firestore will provide the timestamp value at the time of insertion.  On the client, you will receive a [Timestamp](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp-class.html) object, which has a toDate() method to convert it to something native to dart.